# Trying to trace an image using Fourier Transformations, but the output is upside down - why?

Tags: fourier-transform

newbie here.
I've watched a couple videos on Fourier Transformations(mainly 3b1b's), and made my own implementation with Manim. Initially, I fed in the svg of a heart and the output was as expected. Traced out the image correctly. However, when I fed an svg of the letter pi, the output is upside down.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tl0Pf.png) [Input svg](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Pi-symbol.svg)

I have two sets of "vectors", the one with positive exponents(that rotate counter-clockwise), and the other with negative(clockwise). Hence I need to separate out the coefficients(cpos and cneg).

Here are the relevant bits of code:

1. This generates the coefficients given an svg that contains only one path.
   The loops are essentially numerical integration of:

$$\int_0^1 f(t) e^{-2n{\pi}it}\ dt = c_n$$

The 1e-4 is present to scale the coefficients down so the output doesn't go out of my viewport when rendering.

```
SAMPLE = 1000
N=10   # proportional to the number of vectors if you will
filename = "pi"
paths, attributes = svg2paths(f'{filename}.svg')
if len(paths) == 1: 
    path = paths[0]

def point_t(t):
    return path.point(t)

for i in range(N):
    sum=0
    for j in range(SAMPLE):
        sum += 1e-4*point_t(j/SAMPLE)*cmath.exp(i*-2*cmath.pi*1j*j/SAMPLE)
        
    cpos.append(sum)
    
for i in range(N):
    sum=0
    for j in range(SAMPLE):
        sum += 1e-4*point_t(j/SAMPLE)*cmath.exp(i*2*cmath.pi*1j*j/SAMPLE)
        
    cneg.append(sum)
        
print(cpos)
print(cneg)
```

2. Rendering the output

This piece of code will generate the vectors, joined tip to end.
Here, tracker.get_value() is essentially the varying t.
The initial two vectors is the constant vector. The for loop first adds the negative rotation vector, then positive just to make the output a little more chaotic, there's no real reason to do it this way. c_pos[] and c_neg[] are lists that contain the coefficients starting with c[0] = c0. The first elements of both c_pos and c_neg are the coefficients for the constant vector.

The function e2m() takes in in numbers of the form re^i*theta and returns a list [rcostheta, rsintheta, 0]. The library requires the start and end to be in the form of a list.

```
def create_vecs(n):
    
    arrows_pos.append(Arrow(start=ORIGIN, end=e2m(c_pos[0]*cmath.exp(0*2*PI*1j*tracker.get_value())), buff=0))
    arrows_neg.append(Arrow(start=ORIGIN, end=e2m(c_neg[0]*cmath.exp(0*2*PI*1j*tracker.get_value())), buff=0))
    self.add(arrows_pos[0])

    for i in range(1, n):
        arrows_pos.append(Arrow(start=arrows_neg[i-1].get_end(), end=arrows_neg[i-1].get_end() + e2m(c_pos[i]*cmath.exp(float(i)*2*PI*1j*tracker.get_value())), buff=0))
        self.add(arrows_pos[i])
        
        arrows_neg.append(Arrow(start=arrows_pos[i].get_end(), end=arrows_pos[i].get_end() + e2m(c_neg[i]*cmath.exp(-float(i)*2*PI*1j*tracker.get_value())), buff=0))
        self.add(arrows_neg[i])
```

--

Is there anything wrong with the way I compute stuff? Why is my output upside down, and how can I fix this? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Have you checked how the coordinates work? Sometimes the $y$ axis points upwards, sometimes downwards.

Comment: If it is not the coordinates as md2perpe suspects, it may be different definition of the Fourier Transform having the phase of all components spinning in the opposite direction. $\sum c_k e^{-2\pi i k/n}$ instead of $\sum c_k e^{2\pi i k/n}$ Such an error can invert time in 1D case and flips left/right up/down in 2D separable FFT.

Comment: @md2perpe, you're correct! I tried plotting the points that were being outputted by path.point(t) and indeed it plotted an upside down image. This is weird though, because for the heart image, it works fine and the output is of correct orientation.

Comment: @mathreadler while that wasn't the problem, I tried it anyway. I put a negative on the exponents of vectors that were positive and positive for the negative ones, the output was the same. The trace however was in the opposite direction. This corroborates with my thinking of how this is now essentially f(-t), which would of course be tracing it all backwards.
Thank you still, mathreadler and @md2perpe!